# What are the api involved during Kubectl cordon and drain command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am working on automating stuffs on Kubernetes cluster and have a requirement of creating an API to cordon a node. Basically this API should not allow any new pods to enter the cordoned node.

I went through below stack-overflow discussion but couldn't figure out the APIs needed to cordon (and then drain) a node:
[How to access the Kubernetes API in Go and run kubectl commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325091/how-to-access-the-kubernetes-api-in-go-and-run-kubectl-commands)

Answer (score 7):

In order to findout API involved in particular kubectl commmand, use kubectl with flag `--v=9` which displays HTTP request made to API server with their response ([verbose mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging))

### API involved in `kubectl cordon nodename`:

```
GET /api/v1/nodes/node-name
PATCH /api/v1/nodes/node-name
```

In HTTP PATCH Request, 
`Request Body: {"spec":{"unschedulable":true}}`
`Content-Type: "application/strategic-merge-patch+json"`

Under the hood, the Golang client will simply make similar HTTP calls. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43418833/4989632) for making HTTP PATCH request in golang client.

### API involved in `kubectl drain <nodename> --ignore-daemonsets`:

```
PATCH /api/v1/nodes/node-name -> Request Body: {"spec":{"unschedulable":true}}
GET /api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dnode-name -> Get Podlist
POST /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/coredns-7b5c8bfcfc-s94bs/eviction
GET /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/coredns-7b5c8bfcfc-s94bs -> If API call returns 404 means Pod is successfully evicted.
```

Basically, drain command, first cordons the node, then evict the Daemonset Pod(s) from that node.

Comment: `--ignore-daemonsets` isn't evicting the daemonset pods. See: `kubectl drain -h`: 
[...]```If there are DaemonSet-managed pods, drain will not
proceed without --ignore-daemonsets, and regardless it will not delete any DaemonSet-managed pods,
because those pods would be immediately replaced by the DaemonSet controller, which ignores
unschedulable markings.```[...]